# C++ SQLExecDirect INSERT doesn't work

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, odbc, sql-insert

I've wrote a simple SQL C++ Wrapper-Class, where I encountered a real strange Problem. When I call an INSERT-Command with SQLExecDirect, the data does not appear in the SQL Database (SQL Server 2012), although SQLRowCount returns one row. The table, which I'm trying to write to, is named "Person" and has four columns (ID (AUTOINCREMENT), Firstname (nvarchar(100)), Lastname (nvarchar(100)), Birthday (date))

Here is my code:

Class-Constructor (EnvHandle, DBCHandle and StmtHandle are class-members)

```
    SQLDatabase::SQLDatabase()
{
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &EnvHandle);

    SQLSetEnvAttr(EnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);

    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, EnvHandle, &DBCHandle);

    SQLSetConnectAttr(DBCHandle, SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF, SQL_IS_INTEGER);
}
```

Query-Member-Function

```
    int SQLDatabase::ExecuteNonQuery(std::wstring Command)
{
    SQLRETURN RetCode = -1;
    SQLINTEGER RowCount = 0;

    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, DBCHandle, &StmtHandle);

    RetCode = SQLExecDirect(StmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)Command.c_str(), Command.length());
    if (RetCode == SQL_SUCCESS || RetCode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
        SQLRowCount(StmtHandle, &RowCount);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, StmtHandle);
        return RowCount;
    }
    else
    {
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, StmtHandle);
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Function-Call in main.cpp

```
        wcout << "Firstname:\n>";
    wcin >> Firstname;
    wcout << "Lastname:\n>";
    wcin >> Lastname;
    wcout << "Birthday:\n>";
    wcin >> Birthday;

    InsRows = database.ExecuteNonQuery(L"INSERT INTO Person (Firstname,Lastname,Birthday) VALUES ('" + Firstname + L"','" + Lastname + L"','" + Birthday + L"')");
    if (InsRows == -1)
        database.Error();
    else
        std::wcout << InsRows << " rows affected!" << std::endl;
```

As already said, "database.ExecuteNonQuery" returns one row.

When take a look at the table in SQL Management Studio, the datarow hasn't been added. I've already traced the queries on the table. The query appears in the tracelog correctly without any additional info. My IDE is Visual Studio 2013.

Any ideas how I could get the data into the table?

Thanks!

Sebastian

Comment: Did you `commit` the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, whenever a query is executed that changes a table (without error) and the results are not shown,  this means that the changes were not committed.

Looking at your code, you have this:

```
SQLSetConnectAttr(DBCHandle, SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, 
                  (SQLPOINTER)SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF, SQL_IS_INTEGER);}
```

You set the connection attribute to have auto commit turned off.  Either specify you want auto commit on, or issue a call to `SQLEndTran` to commit the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF`, which means your statements won't be automatically committed, so your new record is visible only in your transaction and will never be committed in the database. Try to use the auto-commit feature of the MS SQL Server (setting `SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT` to `SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_ON` or just leave it uninformed since it's the default behaviour) or explicitly begin and commit your transaction.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713605(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much! What a simple solution. It works fine now!